# No mapping for the Unicode character in target multi-byte code page C++

Tags: c++

My code used to work just fine, I just implemented some threads and well now it's broken, I found out the problem is in my variable image_path used in those chunks of code exclusively:

```
//Global vars
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
std::vector<fs::path> image_path; //Vector of paths in which to store all paths to the images
```

**EDIT** Found out if I print el.path().String() it crashes randomly

```
for (const auto& el : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(path, fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied))
    {
        if (is_directory(el) != true)
        {
            if ((el.path().extension().compare(".jpg")) == 0 || (el.path().extension().compare(".jpeg")) == 0 || (el.path().extension().compare(".png")) == 0)
            {
                image_path.push_back(el.path());
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
void hash_function(int start_point)
{
    int counter = 0;
    try
    {
    long int hasher = 1; //Store the hashed value of an image
    std::unordered_map<long int, int>::iterator it; //Iterator for hashmap
    for (int i = start_point; i < image_path.size(); i += THREADS)
    {
        std::cout << "Count = " << counter << "\n";
        cv::Mat processing_image = cv::imread(image_path[i].string(), cv::IMREAD_COLOR); //had to change from image_path[i].u8string() to .string() due to a library update
        hasher = 1; //Must reset hasher to 1
        counter++;
        if (processing_image.dims != 0)
        {
            cv::Mat gray_image; //Define gray image to create gray scale images

            cv::cvtColor(processing_image, gray_image, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            cv::resize(gray_image, gray_image, SIZE);
            for (int j = 0; j < (gray_image.cols - 1); j++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < gray_image.rows; l++)
                {
                    hasher = hasher + gray_image.at<uchar>(l, j); //will leave it like this for now, seems to work
                }
                hasher = hasher * hasher; //just to make hasher even more unique
            }
            //Mutex this bad boi
            mtx.lock();
            //Extremely important things here 
            if (hashmap.empty() == true)
            {
                hashmap[hasher] = i;
                //Add hash value to each path (path is a number of the position of a path in the vector image_path)
            }
            else
            {
                //Solved the counting error by simply skipping the already in check
                it = hashmap.find(hasher);
                if (it != hashmap.end())
                {
                    repeated.push_back(image_path[it->second]);
                    count++;
                    repeated.push_back(image_path[i]);
                    count++;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Add hash value to each path (path is a number of the position of a path in the vector image_path)
                    hashmap[hasher] = i;
                }
            
            }
            mtx.unlock();
            //No more important thingys :D
        }else
        {
            hasher = -1;
        }
    }
    }catch(std::exception & e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

**hash_function** does exactly 58 iterations before returning an error, printed as:  **No mapping for the Unicode character in target multi-byte code page** I've seen that the error is a UTF-8 and ANSI convertion error but I can't find any way of solving this for my code, I can't use u8string() instead of string() because the OpenCV library requieres a string().

Comment: You're sure that the error is related to utf8? What is the 59th path?

Comment: Can you use simple UTF-8 libraries such as https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/ ?

Comment: Note: never call a mutex's `lock` and `unlock` yourself if you can avoid it, use an RAII lock like `std::lock_guard` to ensure that they will get released if an exception is thrown to prevent deadlock.

Comment: @spartygw The path is the same I tried different paths, other images, etc, all of them cause error on the same place.

Comment: @Mgetz That's not the point of the question but I will keep that in mind

Comment: Which line of code is responsible for the error?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.if I try to pass path to String via .string() it returns that error after a set number of iterations

Comment: did you find a solution? im facing that issue, i tried to set codepage to utf-8 also but i didnt work

Comment: @ihsan Use the boost filesystem library, that solved it for me

Answer (score -3):

Solution: Don't use the stupid oficial filesystem library included with windows just use the boost version https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/index.html. It's just faster and has less bugs

Comment: Sorry, all that you stated is not true. Boost filesystem is full of bugs and I needed to write much more workarounds for boost than for the std lib.

Comment: now I'm confused, which one is buggier?